# Elegant way to select a template implementation based on a variable of data types

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated column reader

```
class ColumnIterator {
public:
};

template <typename DT>
class TypedColumnIterator : public ColumnIterator {
using data_type = typename DT::data_type;
public:
    bool HasNext() { ... }
    data_type Next() { ... }
};

class INT {
public:
    using data_type = int32_t;
};

class DOUBLE {
public:
    using data_type = double;
};

template class TypedColumnIterator<INT>;
template class TypedColumnIterator<DOUBLE>;
```

Now I have a table with multiple columns of different types

```
class Table {
    vector<?> types_; // I have question here
public:
    unique_ptr<ColumnIterator> col(int index) {
       // I have question here
    }
};
```

I want to maintain a vector of data types for each column and return a corresponding `TypedColumnIterator` based on the data type.

**Question 1:** What is a good way to maintain the data types? These are very similar to enums. The reason I cannot use enum is as you see, I need to maintain the `data_type` in them. So I create a parent class `DataType` and then let `INT` and `DOUBLE` extends from it. Then I create a static instance as I really only need one static instance for these data types. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

```
class INT : public DataType {
public:
    static INT INST;
}
```

**Question 2** I need a switch in the `col` function to choose the appropriate implementation. This is what I am doing now:

```
template<typename T>
    bool is_INT(T &inst) {
        return is_same<INT, T>();
    }

unique_ptr<ColumnIterator> col(int index) {
    auto type = types_[index];
    if (is_INT(type))
            return unique_ptr<ColumnIterator>(new TypedColumnIterator<INT>());
    ...   
}
```

I feel like this is a bit silly. What's a smart way to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: offtopic: avoid identifiers in ALL_CAPS they are usually used for macros.

Comment: so you have a table where each column is a different type. I got lost in your question, but the usual way to model this is with polymorphism or `std::variant`.

Comment: @bolov Thanks for the hint. Yes you are right. Each column can be of different type. The reason I do not use polymorphism is my column reader uses some encoding library that uses template. I will look at the `std::variant`

Comment: Unrelated: Are you storing types or values in `vector<?> types_;`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes. I leave a ? there because I am not sure what type to use there. Currently I create a parent class `DataType` and use `vector<DataType>`

Comment: @Harper I guess the answer is that you store _values_ in there then - which makes the name `types_` a bit misleading?

Comment: @TedLyngmo that vector stores the data types of the columns. (INT, DOUBLE, etc.)

Comment: @Harper Oh, ok. Got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `std::variant` you could do it like this:

```
class ColumnIterator {
public:
};

template <typename DT>
class TypedColumnIterator : public ColumnIterator {
using data_type = typename DT::data_type;
public:
    bool HasNext() { ... }
    data_type Next() { ... }
};

template<class DT>
struct Column {
    using data_type = DT;
    static auto create_iterator() {
        return std::make_unique<TypedColumIterator<data_type>>();
    }
};

using columns = std::variant<Column<INT>, Column<DOUBLE>>; // can add as many as you want

class Table {
    vector<columns> types_; 
public:
    unique_ptr<ColumnIterator> col(int index) {
        // Applies that lambda to the currently stored type in types_[index]
        // The lambda works for each possible type that can be stored in the variant.
        return std::visit([](const auto& col) { return col.create_iterator(); }, types_[index];
    }
};
```

If that is the best way to do what you want, I cannot say. But it's reasonably good.

Comment: This looks new to me. I will take some time to learn it.